# Pushing to local network git repos Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, apache2

I set up a network git server using a little Raspberry pi following this tutorial: https://linuxhint.com/git_server_http_ubuntu/
The repos were located on a USB drive rather than in /var/www/git. Everything was working hunky-dory until I went and corrupted the microSD card. A fresh install of Raspberry OS on the microSD and everything is back up an running except I can not push to the old git repos. I did not move the repos from the usb drive. I am able to clone them, but not able to push changes.

When I try to push to the old repos I get

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://192.168.0.69/git/project.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've tried setting new permissions on the old git repo:

```
chown root project.git
chmod 777 project.git
```

Additionally, this server is just a local network server (no port forwarding on the home router) therefore I have not set up any user/password on the repositories.

If I create a **new** repos using the script from the tutorial:

```
sudo git-create-repo.sh test
```

The new repos appears on the usb drive just fine and I am able to clone and push to it just fine, so apache2/git are running just fine.

Is there a permission issue I am not aware of (new linux user here)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-move-repository
I just renamed the old repositories, created new ones, and pushed everything to the new repos. Sorry I'm not a git wiz yet!